# Uploads with nginx, Unicorn, Rails 4 and CarrierWave fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, carrierwave, unicorn

I'm developing an application where a user can upload 1-3 images at some point. However, this does not work. When submitting the form, nothing will come through to Unicorn. The only piece of log information I have is this from nginx:

```
2014/09/24 15:28:05 [error] 7301#0: *23953 readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream, client: <my IP>, server: localhost, request: "POST /products HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/<appname>/unicorn.sock:/products", host: "<domain>", referrer: "<domain>/products/new"
```

Also, my browser will try to load the page for some time, and then show a blank page, with the response header giving a 500.

EDIT: okay, as it seems, rack causes a crash when processing file uploads:

```
E, [2014-09-24T21:22:33.505511 #18252] ERROR -- : app error: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
E, [2014-09-24T21:22:33.506288 #18252] ERROR -- : kernel/common/string.rb:103:in `=~'
E, [2014-09-24T21:22:33.506392 #18252] ERROR -- : /srv/<appname>/.rvm/gems/rbx-2.2.10/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:92:in 'get_current_head_and_filename_and_content_type_and_name_and_body'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your unicorn configuration in unicorn.rb and try to modify the timeout